# Operator << overwrite with std::ostringstream issue

Tags: c++

Here's my toy program. It fails to compile with error message " no operator << matches these operands". Any help will be appreciated.

```
struct foo {
    std::string name;
};

std::ostringstream& operator<<(std::ostringstream& os, const foo& info)
{
    os << info.name;
    return os;
}

void insert(const foo& info)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "Inserted here " << info;  // don't work here
}

int main()
{
    foo f1;
    f1.name = "Hello";
    insert(f1);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason

```
os << "Inserted here " << info;
```

does not work is

```
os << "Inserted here "
```

returns a `std::ostream&`, not a `std::ostringstream&`.

Options:

1. Change your function to be use `std::ostream` instead of `std::ostringstream`.

   ```
   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const foo& info) { ... }
   ```
2. Change how you use it. Use

   ```
   os << "Inserted here ";
   os << info;
   ```

I strongly recommend using the first option.

Comment: In # 1, `std::stream& os` -> `std::ostream& os`.